# Highlight Java code inside html textarea using jquery syntax highlighter

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am building a web-app in jsp. I have a textarea in which the programmer writes his java code, and I want to highlight the Java code inside the textarea.

So far I have done:

```
       <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Javascript Libraries/jquery.snippet.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/Javascript Libraries/jquery.snippet.css" />

       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("pre.javacode").snippet("java",{style:"blue"});
        });
       </script>

       </head>

<form id="mypage" action="NewAction.jsp" method="GET">

        <p>Please write in your main class name </p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="codename" name="filename" value="Example" required>
        <p><i>Please write your code here :</i></p>

       <pre class="javacode">
       <textarea  id="codearea" name="jcode" rows="20" cols="100" spellcheck="false" autofocuts>

       import java.io.*;
       import java.util.*;

       class {{codename}}
       {
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {

        }
       }

        </textarea>
        </pre>
        <br />
        <b>stdin:</b>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="arg" value="" >

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submitter" >
        <input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="location.reload(true);">
        </form>
```

And the output I get is:

[image: Output to the above code in browser]

Need some guidance regarding the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textarea` doesn't have the features which you need. It can only display plain text so it ignored all styling, HTML elements and special characters.

Try an editor widget like [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) or [ACE](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about).

Comment: Thank you, for suggesting ACE,It worked well  for the required purpose .